# Automatic CSS Height of Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

quick question. I would like to add a JS program to control the height of one of my bootstrap divs (it's a decorative border on both sides of the page - see picture[image])

I don't want to have to set the height manually (i.e 2000px;)

I was trying something like this, but I couldn't manage it

```
css("max-height", $(window).height());
```

except this just fills up the screen, anyway of filling the body?

Here is the site - davidcodes.co.uk/vintarnBurmese/index.html –

David

Comment: I think `.your-div {height: 100vh}` is ok. If you want to send some space, just used  `.your-div {height: calc(100vh - <number of pixels>px}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting modern browsers, or using modernizr, then using 'vh' units generally works better than %.  When trying to size something relative to the screen height, then percentage units require that the heights of the tree going from your element up through its parents to the body all have predetermined heights.  But the 'vh' units exactly capture what you want.

```css
.yourdiv { height:100vh; }
```

Comment: I did try this now, but unfortunately it doesn't go to the bottom of the page CSS     .sideBar {
        
        background-image: url("images/landing/pattern.jpeg");
        height: 100vh;
        background-repeat: repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        margin-top: -100px;
    }

Comment: the margin-top is moving it.  It is _sized_ to be the same height as your page, but the margin is moving it.  If it is a sidebar, then do you want it to scroll with the rest of the page? If no, then use position:fixed and set the top and bottom where you want, rather than the height. Though, you might have to change the nesting.     .sideBar{ position:fixed; top:100px; bottom: 0px; width:200px; }

Comment: It is way off the bottom currently. Here is a link to my site where you can see how it looks http://www.davidcodes.co.uk/vintarnBurmese/index.html

Comment: It is strange,

I added this which works well in Firefox and Chrome, but Safari doesn't play ball. Strange
<script>

var mainSectionHeight = $(".mainSection").height();

$(".sideBar").height(mainSectionHeight + 100 + "px");

</script>

Answer (score 0):

Replace window with 'body':

```
$el.css('height', $('body').height());
```

Comment: I tried that but no luck, do I need to add anything to the div in the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

This worked in the end (though Safari doesn't like it, FF and Chrome find it ok)

```
<script>
    var mainSectionHeight = $(".mainSection").height();
    $(".sideBar").height(mainSectionHeight + 100 + "px");
</script>
```